# How to Fire Click event of pdf file Chapter Index

Tags: android, pdf

In my application I have requirement some thing like this.I have one Pdf file,on that Pdf file I have first page which is chapter index.Now my requirement is something like when user click on any chapter than it should redirected to selected chapter page.Is there any functionality available in android to achieve this? Might I need to display pdf on a pdfviewer.But what is a possibility?

On alternate solution is that to Convert pdf file to Html pages and to display that html pages on android webview.But it's not a feasible solution i guess.

I tried to find solution on google But no luck,Just need some one's advice to take my decision for this issue.

Thanks